# How should I capture Linux kernel panic stack traces?

Tags: linux, trace, kernel-panic

What's current best practice to capture full kernel stack traces on a Linux system (RHEL 5.x, kernel 2.6.18) that occasionally panics in a device driver?

I'm used to the "old" SunOS way of doing things - crash dumps get written to swap, and on reboot the dump gets retrieved in the local file system.  `man 8 crash` refers to `diskdump`, but that appears to be unsupported. and/or deprecated.

I've played with `kdump`, but it's unclear whether I can get a stack trace from that.  Triggering a panic via Magic SysRq didn't create one.  It also seems wasteful to reserve so much memory (128MB) just for a `kexec` crash recovery kernel.

Comment: The last time I did any of this (2.6.18 era, actually) I used a serial-console configuration to get crash-dump data. That's useless in a VM context these days as nearly every VM system doesn't so serial. No idea if that's latest, though.

Comment: @sysadmin1138: both VirtualBox and QEMU KVM have support for serial ports.

Comment: @cristian Hooray! VMWare doesn't, and that's what I have in front of me.

Comment: @sysadmin1138: well, at least [VMWare 3.2 had support for serial ports](http://www.vmware.com/support/ws3/doc/ws32_devices3.html) :-)

Comment: @sysadmin1138: Funny, I'm trying to think of a VM solution that *doesn't* do serial. And wondering why you would use such a solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to log output in case of a kernel panic with Linux, `kdump` is the way to go.  This is what Red Hat trains people to use and what I have known to be the standard approach.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the stack trace makes it through a netconsole (`/usr/src/linux/Documentation/networking/netconsole.txt`). Worth a try, since it's almost no effort.

Comment: [netconsole.txt](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/netconsole.txt) link for the lazy ones.

Comment: Thanks. SO should link stuff like that automatically ;-)